# Is it possible to have sshd accept passwords only on certain ports?

Tags: ssh

I know it's possible to have `sshd` listen on multiple ports by using multiple `Port` directives. Is it possible to independently adjust the settings per port, however? In particular, is it possible to have one port allow password authentication, but another port disallow it?

Comment: By the way: the reason I'm doing this is that I want to allow passwords on my LAN, but not from the WAN. My WAN firewall only allows connecting to the more restrictive port.

Comment: See also [restriction by IP address(es)](http://askubuntu.com/q/101670) if you prefer to use the standard port number.

Answer (score 34):

This can be accomplished with the `Match` directive.

In `/etc/sshd_config`, declare multiple ports:

```
Port 22
Port 2222
```

Then, at the very end of the file, add the following:

```
Match LocalPort 2222
PasswordAuthentication no
```

All settings will be shared between the ports, except password authentication will be disabled on port 2222.

Comment: Too bad `Match` doesn't work with `AllowUsers`. For anyone that needs to restrict users for a specific port, you're likely stuck with running multiple `sshd` instances.

Answer (score 0):

A single `sshd` process, I don't believe so, but it should be fairly easy to set up a second configuration file and run two `sshd` listeners, one on the password ports and the other on the non-password ports.

Comment: I found that there actually is a way to do this with a single instance of sshd. See the answer I posted. Thanks anyway.